# problem with opening the input file with diff script (in c++)

Tags: c++, makefile, diff, execute

On my assignment , I'm asked to compare the output text file with diff .

my code can't open the input file when I use operator `<` (last line of diff script).

how should I declare the inputfile in main?
what does the last line in `script.sh file` do ?

script.sh file:

```
unzip A4-"$1".zip
(cd A4-"$1"/; make)
cp A4-"$1"/Scheduler.out .
echo "##### DIFF #####"
./Scheduler.out < sample.in | diff sample.out -
```

---

```
int main (int argc , char* argv[]){
    fstream inputFile (argv[1],fstream::in);
    fstream outputFile ("outputFile.out",fstream::out);
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: You should have wrote `./Scheduler.out sample.in | diff sample.out -`, `argv[1]` would contain `"sample.in"` then.

Comment: _"how should I declare the inputfile in main?"_ In case of using `<` the contents of `sample.in` is redirected to `std::cin` of your program. You probably should read about input/output redirection facilities of your _shell_.

Comment: I can't change the script file. it's from an automatic validation

Comment: _"I can't change the script file."_ Then read the input from `std::cin` instead of opening the file explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common pattern for commands is to either read from a file supplied as an argument, or, when an argument is missing, read from `std::cin`. Another common practise for commands in many environments is to accept `-` as an indicator that you want to read from `std::cin`. It could be implemented like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int streamer(std::istream& is) {
    std::ofstream out("outputFile.out");
    if(out) {
        /*...*/
        return 0; // if all's well
    } else
        return 1; // open failed
}

int cppmain(const std::vector<std::string>& args) {         
    if(args.size() && args[0] != "-") { // or do something cleaver to read from all "args".
        std::ifstream is(args[0]);
        if(is)
            return streamer(is);   // read from a file
        else
            return 1;              // open failed
    } else {
        return streamer(std::cin); // read from stdin
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain({argv + 1, argv + argc});
}
```

Remove the `&& args[0] != "-"` part if you get in an argument with someone who likes naming files `-`. I put it there just to show the option.

The last line:

```
./Scheduler.out < sample.in | diff sample.out -
```

Broken down:

`./Scheduler.out < sample.in`

The shell opens `sample.in` for reading and executes `./Scheduler.out`. `std::in` in `.\Schduler.out`, that is usually connected to a terminal, is replaced by the open `sample.in` handle.

`... | diff sample.out -`

`std::cout` from the command `...` replaces `std::cin` in `diff` by the shell. The `-` is an argument that is interpreted by `diff` and means that it will diff one file with the input it gets from `std::cin`, much like what I did in `cppmain` in my example.

Comment: so it doesn't matter what I name the fstream outputFile (the txt file) ?

Comment: It only matters if you have a contract. If you are in control of both sides, no, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I changed it to :fstream outputFile ("output.out",fstream::out); . but it still doens't write anything in the file (seems like it runs the code but can't write anything in it)

Comment: If your changes to the code changes the original question, update the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo _"my answer must seem utterly confusing to everyone else."_ That's what I thought also. Feel free to take the information from my comments, and update your answer to make that less confusing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. I wasn't in a position to make edits when I tried deleting my answer. I rarely get it right when coding via a phone :-)